# reduce font size of the character for the references in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I have a paper with all the references under
`\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\end{thebibliography}`

when I try to put many references either they have to come in several frames how can I shrink the size of the font just for the references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one situation in which the *evil* `allowframebreaks` can be used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{a} test
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want to reduce the font size, you can use any of the font size declarations:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\footnotesize
\bibitem{a} test
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would suggest you not to change the font size (this provokes inconsistency). Another option (but I strongly suggest you *not* to use it) could be the *evilest* `shrink` option (refer to the `beamer` manual).